# How to fix error with lateinit variable in kotlin compose?

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I was making a game with compose, but I'm having problems with the MediaPlayer. MediaPlayer is playing even if you close the app, you can fix this with onResume and onPause methods, but in compose it's harder to do that I can see because compose is initialized much later than onResume (I think?). What should I do?
code:

MainScreen.kt

```
lateinit var mediaPlayer: MutableState<MediaPlayer>
...
@Composable
    internal fun MainContext(){
        val context = LocalContext.current
   ...
        mediaPlayer = remember{ mutableStateOf(MediaPlayer.create(context, R.raw.ost)) }
}
```

MainActivity.kt

```
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            MainContext()
        }
    }

    override fun onPause() {
        super.onPause()
        mediaPlayer.value.stop()

    }
    override fun onResume() {
        super.onResume()
            mediaPlayer.value.start()
    }
}
```

I tried to use `if(mediaPlayer != null)` and `var mediaPlayer: MutableState<MediaPlayer>?` but it gives me wrong result :/

Comment: MediaPlayer isn't suitable to be used as State. Why are you trying to make it into State? Really, it is a UI element, just like what Compose is drawing to the screen, except is audio instead of visual.

Comment: @Tenfour04 well, i used it because i'm using mediaplayer as a background music that changes in compose methods

Comment: why not use property delegate instead of lateinit using lazy, `val mediaPlayer by lazy{MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.ost)}` in Activity and then when an event occurs in UI observe them in activity and then control player from there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you should not mix a class level property with a `remember`ed value in a Composable. All kinds of unexpected/undefined things could potentially occur, as you are experiencing. Since you do need to interact with it outside your Composables, you need to manage creation/recreation of it outside the Composables. This is easier to do if you put it in a ViewModel.

Second, the MediaPlayer type is probably not suitable to use as State. It only has reference equality defined, so all it can do as State is cause recomposition when you replace it with a new MediaPlayer instance. You probably want to recompose when other aspects of its state change as well, so it is an incomplete source of state.

Furthermore, I imagine the designers of compose didn't anticipate complicated classes being used as state. A MediaPlayer has much more than state. It's playing audio and you can send it commands for what to do. So I think it's possible there could be other unexpected bugs by trying to wrap it in State or `remember`ing it in a Composable.

I recommend that you move the MediaPlayer into a ViewModel. This makes it easier to properly maintain the instance when the Activity or Fragment instance is recreated. You can send commands to your ViewModel in `onPause()`/`onResume()` for the ViewModel to pass along to the MediaPlayer. And it can create a new MediaPlayer instance when loading new music, etc.

The relevant state of the MediaPlayer you can keep in a separate MutableState property that uses a data class so you get recompositions at appropriate times.

Very loose example that you can expand/modify it as needed:

```
data class MediaState(
    val uri: Uri?, // null when nothing loaded
    val isPlaying: Boolean,
    val isError: Boolean
)

class MediaViewModel(application: Application): AndroidViewModel(application) {
    private val context: Context get() = application.context

    private var mediaPlayer: MediaPlayer? = null
 
    val mediaState by mutableStateOf(MediaState(null, false, false))

    private fun release() {
        mediaPlayer?.release()
        mediaPlayer = null
        mediaState = MediaState(null, false, false)
    }

    fun loadMedia(uri: Uri) {
        release()
        mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(context, uri).apply {
            setOnErrorListener { _, what, extra ->
                Log("MediaViewModel", "MediaPlayer error with code $what and extra $extra")
                mediaState = MediaState(uri, false, true)
            }
        }
        mediaState = MediaState(uri, false, false)
    }

    fun play() {
        mediaPlayer?.let {
            it.play()
            mediaState = mediaState.copy(isPlaying = true)
        }
    }

    fun pause() {
        mediaPlayer?.let {
            it.pause()
            mediaState = mediaState.copy(isPlaying = false)
        }
    }

    override fun onCleared() {
        release()
    }
}
```

Note, if we really want to do this properly and have the media continue where it left off if we have left the app for a while and the system killed the ViewModel to save memory, then we need to use saved instance state to keep track of the media position and restore it if the ViewModel is recreated. You can look up tutorials on how to use saved instance state in a ViewMdodel.

Or there is an [experimental new Compose feature](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel/viewmodel-savedstate#savedstate-compose-state) that will handle this for you more easily.

Comment: actually viewModels are very usefull, but also as you said i just shouldnt use State for non ui thing